# OpenCV '3.0.0-dev' with Python : Memory leak in While Loop cv2.imread() and cv2.VideoCapture.read() function

Tags: python, opencv, memory-leaks

I have recently updated OpenCV from 2.4.9 to 3.0.0-dev to use some new function in python interface which is used on OpenCV with Python tutorial in the offcial Site.

I use this to pre-built to install http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.0-ocl-tech-preview/tp1/

But I had as issue with camera capturing and also image read in while loop.
for example

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

num = 0
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
    elif k == ord('c'):
        cv2.imwrite('photo'+str(num)+'.jpg',frame)
        num += 1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and also if I change cap.read() with cv2.imread()

```
import cv2

num = 0
while True:
    frame = cv2.imread('D:/Boat/work/hga_counter/test_photo/photo0.jpg')
    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
    elif k == ord('c'):
        cv2.imwrite('photo'+str(num)+'.jpg',frame)
        num += 1
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Memory used by python.exe increasing over time until it's full.

Is my OpenCV installer is outdated and I have to compile OpenCV from most updated source?
or There are any other solution?

Comment: "Is my OpenCV installer is outdated" - no. 3.0 is more 'from the future', but bleeding edge, though. do you get the same problems with 2.4.9 ?

Comment: No, my 2.4.9 can work perfectly. I upgrade this because some function have no interface in Python. My "Outdated" means whether this bug was fixed in the present master commit in Github, because the installer was published in February 2014.

Comment: ah, good to know. when did you download it ? might be suffering from [this bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3470#note-6) (fixed 3.2.2014)

Comment: Yeah!, it's probably this issue. I just downloaded my installer yesterday but Sourceforge said that it wasn't updated since Febuary. Now I try to build OpenCV 3 from the Master branch, but it's still failed haha. I quite bad at it.

Comment: yea, same src. no wonder. either update the code from github, or apply [the same patch](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/2264/files) . installer not updated would be worth making an issue imho.